# How to change font color of specific words in the email body in Outlook Web Add-ins?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an array of string, I would be going to change font color in the email body according to the string array when needed. So far I was able to do so with Word Add-in, but not able to change font color in the outlook add-in. Here's the code that I use to get the text from email body.

```
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, {},
 function (asyncResult) {
                        var text = asyncResult.value;//this is the text
                        var prop = asyncResult.value.sourceProperty;
                    });
```

Comment: The `asyncResult.value` in Outlook will give you the text of the message body. Since that is raw text, there is no `sourceProperty` on it.

Also, not sure how you are trying to change font color, however, you can change your coercion type to Html so that you receive the full Html body of the message, and then tweak it to change the font color.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Why this comment is not posted as an answer? It is clearly answers the question.

Comment: Thanks, I found the way to solve it via HTML by applying inline css to the plain text.